# How to calculate the perimeter of a cuboid?

Tags: function, basic

> Given is the length, breadth, and height of a cuboid. Your task is to calculate its Perimeter.

Note: Formula for the perimeter of the cuboid is `4(Length + Breadth + Height)`

Input

- User Task:
  Since this will be a functional problem, you don't have to take input. You just have to complete the function Perimeter() that takes integers L, B, and H as parameters.
- Constraints:
  1 <= L, B, H <= 100

Output

- Return the length of the Cuboid.

Comment: We don't do homework assignments here, do your own work, show it if it doesn't work.

Comment: What aspect of this task is unclear to you? Obviously the assignment instruction is dead easy: `P = (L + B + H) * 4`. Also, please do mention for what kind of BASIC this is about.

Comment: Share the program you've written and point out where specifically it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The steps of this task are relatively simple.

1. Acquire the length, breadth, and width.
2. Verify that the values are within the required bounds.
3. Calculate the perimeter.
4. Provide either the calculated perimeter or the length, depending on how pedantic the person writing those requirements is.

Number four is probably the hardest part of this task, and you’ll want to contact the person writing the requirements to verify that **Output: Return the length of the Cuboid** is in fact a typo and that you should be returning the *perimeter* of the Cuboid.

In this example, I’m going to assume that this is a trick question and provide the length; however, if it is not a trick question and is instead a typo, you’ll want to replace the length variable (LE) with the perimeter variable (PE) on the output line (80).

```
10 IF NOT (LE < 1 OR LE > 100 OR BR < 1 OR BR > 100 OR WI < 1 OR WI > 100) THEN 60
20 INPUT "LENGTH, BREADTH, WIDTH"; LE, BR, WI

30 IF LE < 1 OR BR < 1 OR WI < 1 THEN PRINT "YOU HAVE ENTERED THE":PRINT "MICROVERSE. PLEASE ENSURE THAT":PRINT "ALL DIMENSIONS ARE AT LEAST 1":PRINT "UNIT."
40 IF LE > 100 OR BR > 100 OR WI > 100 THEN PRINT "YOU HAVE LEFT THE BOUNDS OF":PRINT "THE KNOWN UNIVERSE. PLEASE":PRINT "ENSURE THAT ALL DIMENSIONS ARE":PRINT "NO MORE THAN 100 UNITS."

50 GOTO 10

60 PE = LE + BR + WI
70 PE=PE*4
80 PRINT "THE CUBOID'S LENGTH IS:";LE

90 END
```

BASIC was never known for its readability, and even this short program is probably difficult to follow. Here is the same program in somewhat more readable form:

```
loop while (%length% < 1 or %length% > 100 or %breadth% < 1 or %breadth% > 100 or %width% < 1 or %width% > 100)
    input "Length, Breadth, Width"; %length%, %breadth%, %width%

    switch
    case (%length% < 1 or %breadth% < 1 or %width% < 1)
        wrap You have entered the microverse. Please ensure that all dimensions are at least 1 unit.
    case (%length% > 100 or %breadth% > 100 or %width% > 100)
        wrap You have left the bounds of the known universe. Please ensure that all dimensions are no more than 100 units.
    endswitch
endloop

%perimeter% = %length% + %breadth% + %width%
%perimeter% *= 4
print "The cuboid's length is:";%length%
```

This uses [SuperBASIC](https://www.hoboes.com/Mimsy/hacks/coco/superbasic-trs-80-color-computer/), not as a recommendation (unless, as is very unlikely, the BASIC you happen to be using is on a TRS-80 Color Computer) but simply because I’m familiar with that BASIC preprocessor. These two programs are somewhat equivalent, in that I wrote the more readable code and then used the script to translate it to BASIC.

You can see the steps I outlined above: `input` the dimensions of the cuboid; verify that the dimensions are within the required bounds; and either `loop` back to the `input` request if they are not or calculate the perimeter and `print` the length if they are.

Note that the loop uses the feature of most BASIC implementations that on first encountering a numeric variable the variable is set to zero, which is out of the bounds of the stated requirements. If your variant of BASIC does not do this, you’ll need to assign initial values, most likely with a `DEFINT` or a `LET` statement.